# Tabs are not showing on the website, only about.html shows, home.html and services.html are not showing

Tags: html-lists, nav

Only about.html shows it's contents. index.html and services.html are not showing on the website, it shows file not found requested url.

  Home
- About
- Services

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.